# A theorem about one-dimensional convex sets

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Suppose we have a non-empty convex set which does not consist of only one point such that it belongs to the same line, then this set is either a line segment(closed, half-open or open),a ray(closed or open) or a line. 
How does one prove such obviousness ?  Help

Comment: distinguish cases: the set must be either unbounded n both sides (case 1), bounded on one side (cases 2/3) or bounded on both sides (case 4). in cases 2-4 additionally distinguish whether the supremum/infimum are part of the set. once you have all these cases distinguished, the proofs are trivial

Answer (score 0):

A convex set is connected (because it is path-connected), and connected sets of $\Bbb R$ are intervals.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is as simple as pointed out by @ajotatxe. The following is a more constructive proof, and reflects how to put rigor in such an evident statement. It is just some "mathematical technique."

Call your convex set $C$ and pick a point $x\in C$. Call $\mathcal{F}$ the set of pairs $(a,b)$ of distinct points $a,b\in C$ such that $a\leq x\leq b$ (notice that it is possible that $a=x$ for example). By hypothesis there is more than one point in $C$, so $\mathcal{F}\neq\phi$. The convex condition on $C$ imposes that $[a,b]\subset C$ for every $(a,b)\in\mathcal{F}$. This allows you to write
$$C=\bigcup_{(a,b)\in\mathcal{F}} [a,b].$$
You have then that $C$ is a union of closed intervals with one point in common so it must be an interval (closed, half open or open) a ray (closed, half open or open) or the whole $\mathbb{R}$.